# Troca de menu android

Tags: android

Preciso criar três opções de menus no meu app, 1 para visitantes, outro para cadastrados e outro para admin. Criei 3 arquivos de menus com as opções que preciso, e fazendo a troca manualmente direto na chamada do menu funciona sem problemas. Como posso fazer isso para demonstrar a funcionalidade no login usando por exemplo usarios fakes como nivel1, nivel2 e nivel3?

Comment: Adicione na pergunta o que você já fez.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem! Poderia melhorar a questão?! Tente adicionar seu código mostrando que foi feito ou alguma imagem que simula o que você quer!

Comment: Edita o seu post com o código, é melhor.

Comment: Segue o codigo da chamada do menu:
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

preciso trocar o "activity_home_drawer"por outro dependendo do login usando id de usuarios fakes.